# error: 'Int' is not convertible to '@lvalue Float'

Tags: struct, swift, lvalue

Given the following function:

```
func greatestCommonDenominator(first: Int, second: Int) -> Int {
    return second == 0 ? first : greatestCommonDenominator(second, first % second)
}
```

And a struct with the following stuff in it:

```
struct Fraction {
    var numerator: Int
    var denominator: Int

    func reduce() {
        let gcd = greatestCommonDenominator(numerator,denominator)
        self.numerator /= gcd
        self.denominator /= gcd
    }

    // stuff
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: 'Int' is not convertible to '@lvalue Float'
       self.numerator /= gcd
           ^

error: 'Int' is not convertible to '@lvalue Float'
       self.denominator /= gcd
           ^
```

`'@lvalue Float'`?!?!?  What?  I don't have a Float anywhere in here.  And the documentation seems to suggest that the `/=` should return an `Int` as I'm dividing two `Int`s.  How do I fix this?

---

**ADDENDUM:** I came across this problem working within a struct, however the problem seems reproducible anywhere.

```
let a = 10
a /= 5
```

This will produce the same problem.  Even if we explicitly type `a` as an `Int`:

```
let a: Int = 10
a /= 5
```

The same problem remains.  Swift seems to think the result of the `/=` operator between two Ints is a Float.

---

**EDIT:** The problem with the addendum isn't actually that `a /= 5` doesn't work.  It does actually!

```
var a: Int = 4
var b: Int = 3
a /= b
```

Now `a` is 3.  The problem in the addendum was similar to the struct.  In the addendum, `a` was declared as a `let` rather than a `var`, and as such it is unassignable.

Comment: Careful with that ternary operator there -- the two alternative datatypes are cast to be the same type. I remember a few codepuzzlers where that operator led to unusual bugs. I feel like you should get rid of it here and replace it with a longer statement.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment.  Is there a specific problem with my use of the ternary operator here, or are you just cautioning against it in general?

Comment: I am cautioning againt it in general, and i am ignorant if it is a problem here. I think the datatypes of first and greatestCommonDenominator are different. There may be some behind the scened casting going on that compiles but breaks the intendet function. Nailing the cornercases where it may be an issue is hard during testing. This is not the issue in your code though so i made it a comment. The issue in the code is related to '/='... if you write it out like a = (int)(a/b) it may go away.

Comment: They're all `Int` data types.  The function is called recursively.  Casting doesn't make the error go away--it just changes it.  The 'Float' message is a misleading bug which I've just reported.  `greatestCommonDenominator` is a function that takes two `Int` and returns an `Int`.

Comment: I can see what it is since this is a standard implementation. I still am not too sure of the exact behavior of that operator there. One is an Int, the other one is a function call returning an Int. This would be reason enough for me to avoid the operator. Interesting that the cast did not change it, i will follow this question to see what other answers come along.

Comment: Well, I should clarify, the cast changes the error message in the same way that I described rewriting the assignment changes the error message.  `self.numerator = self.numerator / gcd` provides the same error message as `self.numerator = (Int)(self.numerator/gcd)`  The case doesn't effect anything.  There's a bug with the `/=` operator--not the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start by changing the function to the following you get a more helpful error message:

```
func reduce() {
    let gcd = greatestCommonDenominator(numerator,denominator)
    self.numerator = self.numerator / gcd
    self.denominator = self.denominator / gcd
}
```

Now the error becomes:

```
error: cannot assign to 'numerator' in 'self'
        self.numerator = self.numerator / gcd
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

What may not be immediately obvious to those of us who are coming from Objective-C (or didn't RTFM) is that by default, functions in structs are not allowed to change the properties of a struct.  You can get around this by explicitly declaring the function as a mutating function:

```
mutating func reduce() {
    let gcd = greatestCommonDenominator(numerator,denominator)
    self.numerator /= gcd
    self.denominator /= gcd
}
```

The mutating word solves both errors.

In the case of `/=`, the error is quite cryptic and unhelpful.  I'll be filing a bug report and encourage others to do so as well.

---

**EDIT:** The real problem here has nothing to do with structs or compound assignment operators.

The problem here has to do with the fact that we're trying to assign to an rvalue that's unassignable.  In the case of the struct, the rvalue was unassignable because the function was not declared as mutating.  In the case of the `let` variable, it was unassignable because that's how `let` works.  The error message is still misleading and confusing however.  Rather than suggesting that there might be a type mismatch, the error should inform us that the rvalue is unassignable, just as it would if we tried to assign a `const` in Objective-C.