# Cannot convert the expression's type "NSData!" to "NSData!" error

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization

I feel like the above error must be a Swift bug, or else 1 != 1 is a true statement...

I'm trying to create a JSONObject that I can include in an HTTP Post request's body in order to use the Coinbase API. Here's the code that caused this error.

```
let buttonDict : [String: String] = ["name": "test", "price_string": "0.20", "price_currency_iso": "USD"]
let jsonDict : [String: Dictionary] = ["button": buttonDict]
var jsonError : NSError?
let HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: jsonError)
```

Any clue as to why this error is being thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is a bad error, but `error` is an [inout](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_224) parameter so you must put an `&` in front of it:

```
let HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
    jsonDict,
    options: .PrettyPrinted,
    error: &jsonError
    )
```

Comment: Ah I should have caught this, but thank you for the concise error. Yes it is a pretty terrible error.

Comment: Not the only misleading error in Swift either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713479/error-int-is-not-convertible-to-lvalue-float